# Is it possible to use a conditional jump in assembly without a `cmp` first?

Tags: assembly, x86

So I'm reading through some [assembly source code](https://github.com/redox-os/bootloader/blob/master/x86_64/redoxfs.asm) for learning purposes and came across something very strange (or I may just be a newb):

```
.ver:
    mov al, [redoxfs.header + Header.version +  bx]
    mov ah, [.version + bx]
    cmp al, ah
    jne .ver_err
    inc bx
    jl .ver
```

So in this sub-label we have two jump instructions.

However, about the last jump instruction `jl`. Correct me if I'm wrong, but shouldn't there be a `cmp` before the jump since it's conditional?

I initially thought it was based on `cmp al, ah`, but `jne` jumps if not equal anyway.

Am I missing something?

Comment: In general, yes, you can have a branch instruction anywhere you want. The `jl` mnemonic just means "jump if the sign flag is different from the overflow flag".

Comment: @Banex - Ahhh the flags. I'm such a beginner haha, completely forgot about them. Thank you so much, makes sense now :)

Comment: And the sign and overflow flag is modified by the `inc bx` instruction. (you have to track back the last instruction modifying the flag used by jump, for example `jc` would be using the carry flag from the `cmp al, ah`, as `inc` does not modify CF.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider these 3 kinds of instructions:

- All of the conditional jumps (like `jne`, `jl`, and many more) will jump based on the current setting of one or more of the bits in the FLAGS register.
- Besides the `cmp` instruction, there are many more instructions that will modify some of these bits in the FLAGS register (like `test`, `add`, and many more).
- And then there are lots of instructions that don't modify any of the flags (like `mov`, `push`, and many more).

Examples

```
cmp al, ah
jne .ver_err
```

The `jne .ver_err` jumps based on the flagbits set by **the most recent flags modifying instruction** which is `cmp al, ah` in this case.

```
inc bx
jl .ver
```

The `jl .ver` jumps based on the flagbits set by **the most recent flags modifying instruction** which is `inc bx` in this case.

```
inc bx
lea si, [si+1]
jl .ver
```

Since this interjected `lea` instruction does not modify any flags, the `jl .ver` instruction still jumps based on the flagbits set by the `inc bx` instruction because that's still **the most recent flags modifying instruction**.

Answer (score 3):

The jump-instructions just check the flags corresponding to the suffix. There is no need for a cmp-instruction before the jump. In this case, <s>The inc-instruction just increases the register, but the flags set by the cmp-instructions are tested by the jl instruction.</s> The inc-instructions can set or reset flags. Eg. On overflow, the overflow flag is set. Most processors implement cmp, by substracting the registers, but only write to the flags. So the sub-instruction sets the same flags and can also be used for a comparison. Multiple branches after each other are also allowed, where the flags are rechecked by the jump-instructions.

```
cmp eax, ecx
jl lbl_less
je lbl_equal
jg lbl_greater
```

You can also explicitly set flags, eg. in a called function, which can be checked later by the jump-instructions.

```
stc ;; set carry-flag

;; instructions, which not unintentionally change the carry-flag

clc ;; clear carry-flag

;; ...

jc lbl_carry_is_set ;; check and jump
```

<s>**In your case** it does not make sence, that there is the jl-instruction, because all cases of inequality(which includes "less than") are checked by the jne-instruction, so the branch never occurs from the last line. Maybe there is missing something.</s> The jl tests if the operand of inc is negative.

This behaviour of the instructions is dependent of the processor you have, so x86 behaves differently to Arm and other processors. (In this case, I read a [page](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-3773/instructionset-24/index.html) of the `inc` instruction where there is no much detail about the flags. (A C-compiler needs to know, which flags are modified by the instructions, it can optimize `int i = a - b; if(a < b) {...}` to just a substraction- and a jump-instruction.)

Comment: BTW "the inc-instruction just increases the register", it sets 5 flags too on x86.

Comment: `jl` makes sense after `inc`.  The only flag `inc` doesn't modify is CF.  Other than that, `inc` sets OF and SF the same way `sub bx, -1` does, so it's like a `do { } while( bx++ < -1 );`.  i.e. the loop body runs with `bx` = whatever starting value up to `-1`.  This is a different condition than you'd get with `jne`, which tests `ZF`, because it doesn't loop if `bx` starts out non-negative.  Are you thinking that the `jl` is still testing flags set by `cmp`?  That's the only way your comment makes sense.

Comment: The edit is an improvement, but IA-32 is x86.  Like I said, `inc` writes all flags except CF (the carry flag).  The page you linked is a bit weird in that it only mentions *not* writing CF, and doesn't mention that `inc` writes all the others (although writing flags is the normal case for x86; most integer instructions write flags).  Anyway, an HTML extract of Intel's ISA reference manual for [`inc`](https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/wiki/INC)  and [`jcc`](https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/wiki/Jcc) should be useful.  See also https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info for more links.

Answer (score 3):

You can have as many instructions as you like between the instruction that sets the flags, and the instruction thats tests them, so long as none of them affect the flags you want to test, and detailed knowledge of the instructions and/or a good reference are essential.

```
cmp eax,edx
xchg eax,edx
jne label
```

But you don't need a `cmp` instruction specifically - any instruction that sets flags can then be followed by an instruction that tests the flags. For example

```
sub eax, edx
js label
```