# Confused on what needs to be before JZ in masm x86 assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

So in x86 assembly, I see that if you do

```
or ebx,ebx
jz InvalidDivisor

cmp ebx,0
jz InvalidDivisor
```

So JZ works if you are comparing or doing math before calling JZ.

What happens if you do this:

```
mov ebx,0
jz InvalidDivisor
```

Like would the JZ even execute here since there is no comparison or math? What has to be before a JZ for it to work?

Comment: `mov` doesn't set FLAGS, unlike most integer ALU instructions.  JZ would use FLAGS from whatever previously set it.  FLAGS is just a registers that `jcc` reads.  Check the manual: https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/jcc.  [Is it possible to use a conditional jump in assembly without a \`cmp\` first?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48139412) explains how some instructions do, some don't set FLAGS.

Comment: Terminology: `jz` will definitely execute, but `mov ebx,0` doesn't influence whether it will be *taken* or not.